# Adding Extra Customer Email In Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to know how to call out a extra email filed in woocommerce checkout page. By default there is a email filed for customers to fill in, once he/she checkout they will receive the order copy. I just want to call out another email filed eg Email 2 then that email also should receive the copy. Already tried finding for plugins but didn't work. Any idea to execute..!
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be very close to what you need. But can't say duplicated as you will need to do some coding to get 2nd email address.
Check out.

[Adding a second email address to a completed order in WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce)

To get email field from checkout try

```
get_post_meta( $order_id, '_custom_field', true );
```

now you might want to get $order_id

```
add_action ('woocommerce_thankyou', 'myfunction');
function myfunction($order_id) {
  $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  print $order_id.', '.$order->get_total();
}
```

Hopefully this will take you in right direction.

Comment: Thanks gangesh for the help. Btw i checked that thread before posting here

Comment: @MohammedNaflan and? What problem you are facing implementing it?

Comment: 'add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    $recipient = $recipient . ', me@myemail.com';
    return $recipient;
}'

Cant we call User Email instead of mentioning a email (**me@myemail.com**). What i mean is the site is a franchise concept, where we allow users to signup as a  franchise  and allow to purchase goods directly from us. so here order details will be mailed to admin as well as the customer he orders but he don't get it.

Comment: you said admin and customer. you didn't mention anything about 2nd email in checkout form. Admin and customer always get emails.

Comment: franchise user role is our 2 email , of-course admin will get but if I assign someone as   franchise  they dont get a order copy.
**we dont allow  franchise to access to backend wordpress**

Comment: 1 .Anyone can apply for  franchise
 2. Custom user role( franchise ) is assigned by admin
3.franchise order products from us to his customer 
4.franchise pay for the order 
**Admin** And **franchise** get the order copy  via mail but franchise not

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer. Hopefully you can implement it as you need.

Comment: BTW where these codes to be implemented in function.php?

Comment: Yes. It will go in function.php .

Comment: i tried, but it dosen't add a new filed on checkout page

Comment: Add? But i thought you added already and just needed to send order email to that field. You are confusing here.

Comment: Al ready used this code `
[link] (https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/11338)

Comment: Not sure what is done and whats not. Adding new checkout field' solution is easily available. And rest email thing you can try my answer. Hope this sorts your issue.