# Adding extra email address who receives email like admin - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

Is there any way to add a new email address along with admin email who receives same email as the admin.like : on placing an order admin receives 'NEW ORDER RECEIVED'  but customers receives 'THANKS FOR YOUR ORDER' I know  how to add an email on placing order as customer but is there any way where admin and that added email recipient will receive same email.and after the order is placed remove that email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add additional email to receive mail from woo commerce. Here you can find out more detail  : [`https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce)