# Send admin new order email to logged in user as well

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-meta, email, users

I need to be able to send the **admin email for a new order** also to the e-mail address **linked to the current logged in user**.

This is required as **1 account** is for **different people** (people who give a present), but the originally created account is still linked to the original user e-mail address (from the parents).

This way, parents are notified via email when a new gift is given.

I don't seem to find the fix here. I started to adapt the code from [Adding a second email address to a completed order in WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce), but now I want to dynamically add the e-mail address of the user.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
/* SEND ADMIN E-MAIL TO LOGGED IN USER */
/* --- */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

/* Add parents e-mail address to new order admin mail */
function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);
    $recipient = $recipient . ', ' . $user_info->user_email;
    return $recipient;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have makes sense, except that your variable names dont match. You have $object in your function definition and in the function code you are trying to use $order.

Adjusted:

```
/* SEND ADMIN E-MAIL TO LOGGED IN USER */
/* --- */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

/* Add parents e-mail address to new order admin mail */
function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $order) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);
    $recipient = $recipient . ', ' . $user_info->user_email;
    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That does the trick. Code is working now !